# Python- Reading two n-spaced sequences as a list, subtracting the lists and printing the greatest difference.[CodeChef]

Tags: python-3.x

I was working with a problem on CodeChef and I am stuck with one of the sub task being incorrect.

Problem statement:

https://www.codechef.com/AUG19B/problems/MSNSADM1

You are given two sequences. For each valid i, player i scored
Ai
goals and committed 
Bi
fouls. For each goal, the player that scored it gets 
20
points, and for each foul, 
10
points are deducted from the player that committed it. However, if the resulting number of points of some player is negative, this player will be considered to have 
0
points instead.

You need to calculate the total number of points gained by each player and tell Alex the maximum of these values.

> Input:

The first line of the input contains a single integer 
T
denoting the number of test cases. The description of 
T
test cases follows.

The first line of each test case contains a single integer 
N
.
The second line contains 
N
space-separated integers (for no. of goals).
The third line contains 
N
space-separated integers (for no. of fouls).

> Output:

For each test case, print a single line containing one integer ― the maximum number of points.

> Constraints:

1≤T≤100

1≤N≤150

0≤Ai≤50
for each valid 
i

0≤Bi≤50
for each valid 
i

My approach to this was to create 2 lists and multiply each element of first by 20, second by 10 and then create a list c, which has the difference of each elements.

```
try:
    t= int(input())
    while(t != 0):
        t -= 1
        n = int(input())
        a_i = list(map(int, input().split()))
        b_i = list(map(int, input().split()))
        a = [i * 20 for i in a_i]
        b = [i * 10 for i in b_i]

        for i in range(0 , len(a)):
            if a[i] < 0:
                a[i] = 0

        for i in range(0 , len(b)):
            if b[i] < 0:
                b[i] = 0

        c = [i - j for i, j in zip(a, b)]
        print(max(c))

except:
    pass
```

All the tasks seems to be showing correct answer except one. I can't seem to understand what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the given indentation you are only printing the last testcase.

You create lots of `list`'s in between that are not needed but take time to create/instantiate etc.

You loop over your data twice to eleminate the negative values - also not needed.

Use generators instead:

```
try:
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        n = int(input())
        a_i = map(int, input().split())  # dont list(...) this
        b_i = map(int, input().split())  # dont list(...) this

        # get the max - negatives are irrelevant, they are removed when printing
        m = max(goals * 20 - fouls*10 for goals, fouls in zip(a_i,b_i))

        # if _all values_ are negative, print 0 else print the max value
        # you need to print _each_ testcase, not only the last as your code does
        print(max( (m,0) ))
except:
    pass
```

Comment: The indentation was a typing mistake. I get what my mistake was, I was not addressing to the condition when the difference could be 0. _If the resulting number of points of some player is negative, this player will be considered to have 0 points instead._

Answer (score 1):

```
t= int(input())
while(t != 0):
    t -= 1
    n = int(input())
    a_i = list(map(int, input().split()))
    b_i = list(map(int, input().split()))
    c=[]
    a = [i * 20 for i in a_i]
    b = [i * 10 for i in b_i]

    c =list(map(int.__sub__, a, b))
    for line in c:
        if line < 0:
            line = 0
    print(max(c))enter code here
```

Comment: Thanks. The only thing I was doing wrong was not addressing the condition that the difference can be 0.